# Sending a POST request with parameters and reading response

Tags: java, android, post, jsoup, httpurlconnection

I want to send a POST request to https://parts-of-speech.info/tagger/tagger with parameters being "text=" and "language=".

So far I've tried three procedures: JsonObjectRequest, Jsoup.connect, and HttpURLConnection in AsyncTask, none of which seem to work.

This is the code for JsonObjectRequest:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        params.put("text", "This is a text.");
        params.put("language", "en");

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, stringurl, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //TODO: handle success
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

This is the track trace:

```
2019-10-22 17:46:04.390 19530-19530/? I/hsulaiman.ling: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-10-22 17:46:04.992 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/hsulaiman.ling: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-10-22 17:46:05.000 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/chatty: uid=10082(com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu) identical 10 lines
2019-10-22 17:46:05.000 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/hsulaiman.ling: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-10-22 17:46:05.020 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-10-22 17:46:05.038 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-10-22 17:46:05.337 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/hsulaiman.ling: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-22 17:46:05.339 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/hsulaiman.ling: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-22 17:46:05.499 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-22 17:46:55.482 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 7ae04e7, Ia74c9b5270
    Build Date                       : 09/20/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.4.R1.09.00.00.453.030
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2019-10-22 17:46:55.483 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2019-10-22 17:46:55.483 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 17:46:55.474 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:375092): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=11046 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=2681 pcomm="main" pgid=19530 pgcomm="hsulaiman.lingu"
2019-10-22 17:46:55.487 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-10-22 17:46:55.491 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-22 17:46:55.492 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-22 17:46:55.492 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-22 17:46:55.492 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-10-22 17:46:55.520 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 17:46:55.521 19530-19555/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 17:46:56.438 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2648 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2019-10-22 17:46:56.445 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-10-22 17:46:56.449 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/chatty: uid=10082(com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu) identical 2 lines
2019-10-22 17:46:56.449 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-10-22 17:47:00.065 19530-19628/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-22 17:47:00.569 19530-19628/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/Volley: [28257] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://parts-of-speech.info/tagger/tagger/
2019-10-22 17:47:00.581 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/System.err: com.android.volley.ClientError
2019-10-22 17:47:00.581 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199)
2019-10-22 17:47:00.581 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
2019-10-22 17:47:00.581 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2019-10-22 17:47:00.581 19530-19530/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

This is the code for Jsoup:

```
Connection.Response response =
                Jsoup.connect(stringurl)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                        .timeout(10 * 1000)
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .data("text", text)
                        .data("language", "en")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();
        Document document = response.parse();
```

It crashes at "execute":

```
2019-10-22 18:39:56.390 29720-29720/? I/hsulaiman.ling: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-10-22 18:39:56.546 29720-29720/? W/hsulaiman.ling: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-10-22 18:39:56.547 29720-29720/? I/chatty: uid=10082(com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu) identical 10 lines
2019-10-22 18:39:56.548 29720-29720/? W/hsulaiman.ling: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-10-22 18:39:56.561 29720-29720/? I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-10-22 18:39:56.572 29720-29720/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-10-22 18:39:56.700 29720-29720/? W/hsulaiman.ling: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-22 18:39:56.701 29720-29720/? W/hsulaiman.ling: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-22 18:39:56.782 29720-29720/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-22 18:39:56.835 29720-29740/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 7ae04e7, Ia74c9b5270
    Build Date                       : 09/20/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.4.R1.09.00.00.453.030
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2019-10-22 18:39:56.836 29720-29740/? I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2019-10-22 18:39:56.836 29720-29740/? D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 18:39:56.831 29720-29720/? W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:379229): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=11046 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c82,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=2681 pcomm="main" pgid=29720 pgcomm="hsulaiman.lingu"
2019-10-22 18:39:56.841 29720-29740/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-10-22 18:39:56.844 29720-29740/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-22 18:39:56.844 29720-29740/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-22 18:39:56.844 29720-29740/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-22 18:39:56.844 29720-29740/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-10-22 18:39:56.895 29720-29740/? D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 18:39:56.896 29720-29740/? D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-22 18:39:58.981 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2648 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2019-10-22 18:39:58.990 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-10-22 18:39:58.992 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/chatty: uid=10082(com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu) identical 2 lines
2019-10-22 18:39:58.992 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-10-22 18:40:02.846 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-22 18:40:02.851 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-10-22 18:40:02.853 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu, PID: 29720
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6612)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6581)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25904)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6612) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6581) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25904) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:705)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:295)
        at com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu.MainActivity.buttonOnClick(MainActivity.java:68)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6612) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6581) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25904) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-10-22 18:40:02.869 29720-29720/com.jwanhsulaiman.lingu I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29720 SIG: 9
```

I'm supposed to receive a JSON object, for example:

```
{
    "taggedText": "John_NNP likes_VBZ the_DT blue_JJ house_NN at_IN the_DT end_NN of_IN the_DT street_NN ._. "
}
```

I've searched the web for solutions to no avail. What is the best way to achieve the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below.

```
 JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
 try {
      parameters.put("text" , "sample text");
      parameters.put("language", "en");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
 JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, stringurl, parameters,
     new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           //TODO: handle success
        }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
      });

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

**UPDATE**

From your `track trace`

> Unexpected response code 404 for https://parts-of-speech.info/tagger/tagger/

I test your URL using `postman` it gives `response 404` like you. but when I try without the last **backslash** it works fine.

You should **remove** the last **backslash** from your **URL**. your URL should be like

> stringurl = "https://parts-of-speech.info/tagger/tagger"

Comment: post your full `stack trace`.

Comment: You're right, that's it, thank you so much!! Alas it returns an empty key, like this: {"taggedText":""} no matter the given text. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: If you not pass parameter you will get an empty string like you already got. if you pass parameter in right way then you should get a response like `{
    "taggedText": "\"_$[ hello_FM \"_$[ "
}`

Comment: Here is the screenshots of my test using `postman`. [with parameter](https://i.imgur.com/e3CFKAj.png) and [without parameter](https://i.imgur.com/8M9CJmi.png).

Comment: I'm passing the parameters as you are and still no luck :(